# Problems installing imagemagick: look like compilation errors

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, imagemagick

I'm trying to install ImageMagick 6.4 on a new (Linux Mint 18) linux installation.  I want 6.4 since that's the version we have on our server.

I downloaded a tar.gz, unzipped it, ran `configure` and then tried `make`.  I instantly get a ton of errors like this:

```
$ make

make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/max/software/imagemagick/6.4/ImageMagick-6.4.0'
/bin/bash ./libtool --silent --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./config   -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libxml2  -g -O2 -Wall -W -pthread -MT coders/coders_art_la-art.lo -MD -MP -MF coders/.deps/coders_art_la-art.Tpo -c -o coders/coders_art_la-art.lo `test -f 'coders/art.c' || echo './'`coders/art.c
In file included from coders/art.c:5
./magick/quantum-private.h: In function ‘PopDoublePixel’:
./magick/quantum-private.h:85:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
   *((double *) quantum)=(double) (pixel*quantum_state->scale+
   ^
./magick/quantum-private.h: In function ‘PopFloatPixel’:
./magick/quantum-private.h:115:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
   *((float *) quantum)=(float) ((double) pixel*quantum_state->scale+

In file included from magick/blob.c:65:0:
/usr/include/zlib.h:1536:30: note: expected ‘gzFile {aka struct gzFile_s *}’ but argument is of type ‘FILE * {aka struct _IO_FILE *}’
ZEXTERN const char * ZEXPORT gzerror OF((gzFile file, int *errnum));
                          ^
```

I don't really know much about compilation but these all look like some sort of fundamental failure to compile or run the code.  There's tons of them.  Can anyone guess what I'm missing, or what I've done wrong?

EDIT: The full output is here: http://pastebin.com/v01aj8hu

Comment: I see no actual error in that output, only warnings. If there's an error (which makes the compilation terminate), then maybe post that.

Comment: I've added the full output in a pastebin, thanks.

Comment: _Looks like_ it's trying to use `zlib` in the wrong way. Maybe it's expecting a newer version of `zlib` than what is available?  IIRC, one may disable `zlib` support for ImageMagick with `--without-zlib` when configuring... But that may not be what you want to do.

Comment: I just tried that as an experiment - still get tons of warning and errors and general full-of-fail...

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue and it is related with the building machine, your standard libs for C and C++ are newer than the ones needed by your ImageMagick version. Upgrading the ImageMagick version would make the trick.

Another solution would be to use a container or another machine to build this.

Hope this information helps someone else :).